# $\lim_{x \to 0} \cos (\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus

How To Find $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \; \cos(\frac{1}{x}) $$

Comment: Hint: You can find values of $x$ arbitrary close to $0$ such that they give $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ equal to $-1$ or $1$.

Comment: try two sequences $x_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi}$ and  $x_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: In other words, the direct answer is: You can't. The limit does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The function is strongly oscillating at $x=0$ so this suggests that the limit does not exist (although, for example, $\lim_{x\to 0}x\cos\left(\frac1x \right)$ does exist)

Taking a special sequence $x=\frac{1}{n\pi}, n\to \infty$ gives an formal proof.